Limit of Stopping time of Sum of Random Variables
I'm working on a problem set, the question is presented:

Let $X_n$ be independent random variables, and let $$Y_k = \sum_{n=1}^k X_n$$ For $L > 0$, define $\tau_L^+ = \inf\{k|Y_k \geq L\}$ and $\tau_L^- = \inf\{k|Y_k \leq -L\}$. Let $p_L = P(\tau_L^+ < \tau_L^-)$.
Give an example where $X_n$ are random variables, not necessarily identically distributed, satisfying $E(X_n) = 0$, but $\lim_{L\to\infty} p_L$ does not exist.

I'm finding a hard time coming up with an example, more than the example I'm not really sure how to go on and prove it actually is correct.
Any help, hints, or partial solutions would be great!

Let $m$ be a positive integer. For $n\in(2^m,2^{m+1}]$ , when $m$ is even, let
$$
X_n=\begin{cases}
2^{m^3}, &\text{with probability }2^{-m};\\
-\frac{2^{m^3-m}}{1-2^{-m}}\ (<-2^{m^3-m}), &\text{with probability }1-2^{-m},
\end{cases}
$$
then $\mathbb{E}(X_n)=0$.
Note that
$$
|S_{2^m}|\le 2^{(m-1)^3}\cdot 2^m\ll 2^{m^3-m}
$$
Consequently, the sign of $S_k$, $k\in (2^m,2^{m+1}]$, will be solely determined by the sign of
$$
\tilde S_k^{(m)}=\sum_{n=2^m+1}^k X_n
$$
Let $L=L(m)=2^{m^3-m}$. Then with predominant probability $\tilde S_k^{(m)}$ will reach $(-\infty,-L]$ before $[+L,+\infty)$, and since $|S_k|\ll L$ for $k\le 2^m$, we conclude
$$
p_{L}\approx 0.
$$
Now, for odd $m$, and $n\in(2^m,2^{m+1}]$ let
$$
X_n=\begin{cases}
-2^{m^3}, &\text{with probability }2^{-m};\\
+\frac{2^{m^3-m}}{1-2^{-m}}\ (<-2^{m^3-m}), &\text{with probability }1-2^{-m},
\end{cases}
$$
and by the similar argument
$$
p_{L}\approx 1.
$$
Hence $p_L$ cannot converge.
